# Create a general rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: 8, path-aliases, .htaccess, routes

In an upgrade scenario I have to provide some alias URLs like `www.server.com/reading_23.html` that should actually deliver `www.server.com/reading/23`.

I spent lots of hours trying to make that work by adding a line in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule reading_(.*).html reading/$1
```

I have put that line into the standard D8 .htaccess, right after `RewriteBase /`. Unfortunately none of my attempts worked. The `/reading` is a path that's provided by one of my `modules.routing.yml`.

EDIT, 18.1.
This seems to be very special for Drupal because it just doesn't work with the existing D8 redirects. I can only make a redirection (`[L,R]`) work but I don't want my end-users to see the `reading/23` path in their browser.
So actually the question is how to make URLs like `reading_23.html` possible with Drupal, the routing parameters can only live as separate parts of the path (like `reading/{number}` is ok but `reading_{number}.html` is bad).

Anyone who knows how to do this?

I do not want to create aliases in my Drupal DB for all node-Ids.

[EDIT Nr 2. 18.Jan 2017]

The Solution is an inbound Path Processor like 4k4 wrote. Thanks a lot.

[END EDIT]

Comment: I think your issue is you're trying to Rewrite a URL to a URL rewrite. After you rewrite `reading_$1.html` into `reading/$1`, that then is rewritten to `index.php?q=reading/$1`. So you shouldn't rewrite to `reading/$1`, instead try to rewrite it straight into `index.php` so it doesn't go through the second pass.

Answer (score 3):

I think your rewrite collides with the other rewrites in drupal standard .htaccess. Try a redirect. The redirect will be executed right away and the rest of .htaccess will no longer be processed. And it will also tell search engines that the url has changed.

```
RewriteRule reading_(.*).html reading/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hm, I wanted to keep the reading_23 URL in the users Browser. When I redirect [R] the new URL pops up...

Comment: Use an inbound path processor. If you change the path here, it will not be visible in the browser. Example from core for the front page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21PathProcessorFront.php/function/PathProcessorFront%3A%3AprocessInbound/8.2.x

Comment: Fantastic, the inbound path processor is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Rewrites this code for your problem in .htaccess. The code will work for any string in between `reading_` and `.html`

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^reading_(.*)\.html$ http://www.server.com/reading/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope, this works fine for you.